# cat an file programs fail to acess a file but vi works properly (Debian)

Tags: debian, io, firmware, dmesg, bug

I have getting some problems with my system after a bad reset via ctrl+alt+del. Since then errors related to ACPI and ata6 are reported. Trying to get a solution to this (in a savage way:I am n00b), I started to test the contends in the directory /sys/class/ata_port/ata6/.What I mean with test is looking for a useful information or something that could inspire me to learn or to do a clearer question in a forum. Anyway, apart from  this problem, a curious thing happens:

When I use **cat** or **file** with the file /sys/class/ata_port/ata6/autosuspend_delay_ms I get **"I/O erro"**.
But... using **vi** I read the contends of the file that is **"1"**.

**MAIN QUESTION**: Why and how that happens? (This is really freaking me out! **vi** is more "userland" and **cat** and **file** is more "kernelland")

**SIDE QUEST:** If someone have a idea how to resolve this system problem, I will be very glad! Now, the system boots only using boot parameter "acpi_enforce_responses=lax" (with a good luck!Sometimes even this isn't sufficient to boot and the monitor losts communication (NULL output))"

***Details:***

**system:** Linux debian 4.9.0-11-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.189-3+deb9u2 (2019-11-11) x86_64 GNU/Linux

**Erro System Log**: acpi PNP0A03:00: _OSC failed (AE_NOT_FOUND); disabling ASPM

**OUPUT: dmesg|grep 'fail\|erro'**

[    0.234571] acpi PNP0A03:00: _OSC failed (AE_NOT_FOUND); disabling ASPM

[    2.239147] ata6.00: failed to IDENTIFY (I/O error, err_mask=0x100)

[    7.971272] ata6.00: failed to IDENTIFY (I/O error, err_mask=0x100)

[   13.603109] ata6.00: failed to IDENTIFY (I/O error, err_mask=0x100)

[   20.228845] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro

[   23.170590] r8169 0000:05:00.0: firmware: failed to load rtl_nic/rtl8168e-1.fw (-2)

[   23.174073] r8169 0000:05:00.0: Direct firmware load for rtl_nic/rtl8168e-1.fw failed with error -2

**OUPUT: dmesg|grep -i 'ata'**

[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000cffb0000-0x00000000cffbdfff] ACPI data

[    0.000000] NODE_DATA(0) allocated [mem 0x22fff9000-0x22fffdfff]

[    0.000000] Memory: 8089844K/8387896K available (6288K kernel code, 1162K rwdata, 2880K rodata, 1424K init, 656K bss, 298052K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)

[    0.235157] pci 0000:00:11.0: set SATA to AHCI mode

[    1.692680] Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 12288k

[    1.744345] libata version 3.00 loaded.

[    1.746053] scsi host0: pata_atiixp

[    1.747319] scsi host1: pata_atiixp

[    1.747387] ata1: PATA max UDMA/100 cmd 0x1f0 ctl 0x3f6 bmdma 0xff00 irq 14

[    1.747388] ata2: PATA max UDMA/100 cmd 0x170 ctl 0x376 bmdma 0xff08 irq 15

[    1.748026] ahci 0000:00:11.0: AHCI 0001.0200 32 slots 4 ports 6 Gbps 0xf impl SATA mode

[    1.749170] ata3: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m1024@0xfe7ffc00 port 0xfe7ffd00 irq 25

[    1.749172] ata4: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m1024@0xfe7ffc00 port 0xfe7ffd80 irq 25

[    1.749173] ata5: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m1024@0xfe7ffc00 port 0xfe7ffe00 irq 25

[    1.749175] ata6: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m1024@0xfe7ffc00 port 0xfe7ffe80 irq 25

[    1.928821] ata1.01: ATA-9: WDC WDS240G2G0A-00JH30, UF450000, max UDMA/133

[    1.928823] ata1.01: 468877312 sectors, multi 1: LBA48 NCQ (depth 0/32)

[    1.929427] ata1.01: limited to UDMA/33 due to 40-wire cable

[    1.952293] ata1.01: configured for UDMA/33

[    1.952499] scsi 0:0:1:0: Direct-Access     ATA      WDC WDS240G2G0A- 0000 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5

[    2.076991] ata5: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)

[    2.077014] ata4: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)

[    2.237428] ata6: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)

[    2.237447] ata3: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)

[    2.238304] ata3.00: ATA-7: ST3160815AS, 3.CHH, max UDMA/100

[    2.238306] ata3.00: 312581808 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32)

[    2.239147] ata6.00: failed to IDENTIFY (I/O error, err_mask=0x100)

[    7.493471] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/100

[    7.493630] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      ST3160815AS      H    PQ: 0 ANSI: 5

[    7.969453] ata6: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)

[    7.971272] ata6.00: failed to IDENTIFY (I/O error, err_mask=0x100)

[    7.971275] ata6: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps

[   13.601480] ata6: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)

[   13.603109] ata6.00: failed to IDENTIFY (I/O error, err_mask=0x100)

[   19.233505] ata6: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)

[   19.884310] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)

[   20.449088] acpi_cpufreq: overriding BIOS provided _PSD data

Comment: HEY! What is "Server Fault!?". I was logged in Ubuntu community! What to do in order to move this question to a proper site?

Comment: What is connected to ata6.  HDD, DVD, ... ?  BTW, ctrl-alt-del can't hurt your hardware.

Comment: Have a look inside your system, write down what disk devices you see.  Start "dmesg | grep ata" and see which are correctly identified.  The one that remains is connected to ata6.

Comment: |grep ata6:


[ 1.749175] ata6: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m1024@0xfe7ffc00 port 0xfe7ffe80 irq 25

[    2.237428] ata6: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)

[    2.239147] ata6.00: failed to IDENTIFY (I/O error, err_mask=0x100)

[    7.969453] ata6: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)

[ 7.971272] ata6.00: failed to IDENTIFY (I/O error, err_mask=0x100)

[ 7.971275] ata6: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps

[ 13.601480] ata6: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
[ 13.603109] ata6.00: failed to IDENTIFY (I/O error, err_mask=0x100)

Comment: [   19.233505] ata6: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)

I couldn't read this output. There is no information like HDD or SSD.

Comment: Please read my previous comment.  "dmesg | grep ata"  not ata6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The disk that is not in this list, is the one that is defective.

In your output I see these disks

```
[ 1.928821] ata1.01: ATA-9: WDC WDS240G2G0A-00JH30, UF450000, max UDMA/133
[ 2.238304] ata3.00: ATA-7: ST3160815AS, 3.CHH, max UDMA/100
```

A Western Digital Green 240Gb and a Seagate Barracuda 160Gb.  Two hard disks.  Could it be that the problem drive is a DVD or CDROM?   That would be good news: no data lost.  If I were you, I would simply remove the sata or pata cable and put it back, you never know it's simply a bad connection.

Comment: I am seeking deeply. No such kind of output exists.

Comment: Anyway, thank you for your help! You are helping a lot! (at least, giving me hope ;-) )

Comment: Pehaps because :

[    7.971272] ata6.00: failed to IDENTIFY (I/O error, err_mask=0x100)

Comment: Perhaps there is only one drive in your system, no CD or DVD drive ?  I am talking nonsens, since you can work on it.  And if there is ata6, there must be ata1 to 5 too.

Comment: full output in the main post